# Why "-190732550-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ" datetime does not fail to parse

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, zoneddatetime, java-17

Consider the following snippet:

```
String dateTimeStr = "-190732550-05-25T15:14:51.136Z";
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

log.info("String: {}", dateTimeStr);
log.info("ZonedDateTime: {}", dateTime);
log.info("EpochMilli: {}", dateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```

Output:

```
String: -190732550-05-25T15:14:51.136Z
ZonedDateTime: -190732550-05-25T15:14:51.136Z
EpochMilli: -6019000079877908864
```

I expected the above would throw `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException`.

**Edit**

`"190732550-05-25T15:14:51.136Z"` throws `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException`. Shouldn't be valid too?

Comment: That looks like a value that's May 25th about 190 million years BC. It appears to be within the range of values that java.time supports... which surprises me, but if you accept that range, it looks like a reasonable string.

Comment: The minimum supported year seems to be [-999999999](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html#MIN_VALUE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

This:

```
Instant.parse( "-190732550-05-25T15:14:51.136Z" )
```

… succeeds because your input of a few hundreds of millions of years lies within the range of +/- one billion years in that class.

## -1,000,000,000 < -190,732,550 < +1,000,000,000

Use `Instant` class to parse an input string ending in `Z`, which means an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. No time zone involved, so no need for `ZonedDateTime`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "-190732550-05-25T15:14:51.136Z" ) ;
```

This input will indeed be parsed successfully. You are supplying a year that lies within the range of possible values for that data type.

The minimum value for `Instant` is represented in the predefined constant [`Instant.MIN`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#MIN). To quote the Javadoc:

> The minimum supported Instant, '-1000000000-01-01T00:00Z'.

That is the year -1,000,000,000 (one billion).

You input year is only -190,732,550 (hundreds of millions). So your value fits within the accepted range of +/- one billion years.

The `Instant` class is currently implemented as a pair of 64-bit `long` integers. One is for a number of whole seconds since the first moment of 1970 UTC. The other is for a count of nanoseconds in the fractional second. So this class is capable of supporting a wide range of values.

### Positivity

Note that positive-numbered years with more than four digits must prepend a PLUS SIGN character.

To quote the Javadoc for the predefined constant [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) named [`ISO_LOCAL_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE), which is used by [`ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME), which is used by [`ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME), which is used by [`ISO_INSTANT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT) when calling [`Instant.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) (emphasis mine):

> Four digits or more for the year. Years in the range 0000 to 9999 will be pre-padded by zero to ensure four digits. Years outside that range will have **a prefixed positive or negative symbol.**

This succeeds:

```
Instant.parse( "+190732550-05-25T15:14:51.136Z" )
```

… whereas this fails:

```
Instant.parse( "190732550-05-25T15:14:51.136Z" )
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/qMoH9P).

Comment: @lkatiforis Wow, I confirmed your finding. See [here on IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/qMoH9P) in Java 12. I’ll investigate later, when I am at a computer.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for that fact. I updated the Answer to cover that. I rooted out the nested documentation confirming your point.