# Java 8 DateTimeFormatter parse fails for ISO dates far in future

Tags: java, java-time

I encountered an issue where `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME` where date cannot be parsed if year is more then 9999.
I was looking for a bug report or to understand what I am doing wrong.
Also - `JodaTime` parse works for the same string.
Java version - 8.
This test fails:

```
    public void testParseFarInTheFuture()
    {
        String str = "10000-04-11T01:24:55.887-03:56";

        DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parse(str);
    }
```

Same test with year 9999 works.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elastic Search and Y10k (years with more than 4 digits)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62541394/elastic-search-and-y10k-years-with-more-than-4-digits). In other words, years containing more than 4 digits need a `+` or `-` at the start of the string.

Comment: See similar Question, [*Why "-190732550-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ" datetime does not fail to parse*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71886611/642706).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Prepend `+`

- Years with more than four digits are expected to have a **leading PLUS SIGN** character (`+`) for positive years (AD).
- Negative years (BC) with any count of integers always lead with a MINUS SIGN (`-`).

The *java.time* classes generally follow the rules laid down in the ISO 8601 standard. See Wikipedia page on [handling years in ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years).

Code:

```
OffsetDateTime ldt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "+10000-04-11T01:24:55.887-03:56" ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/8dOuN6).